# Transfer a text value from a drop down list into it's respective database ID - sql insertion and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble converting a drop down list value (:Artist, text) into its respective ID (Artist_ID, num) and inserting it into the event table. Same problem with Venue_ID.

```
<?php
        $artist = 
                'SELECT Artist_ID
                 FROM artist
                 WHERE :Artist = Artist_Name
                ';
        $venue = 
                'SELECT Venue_ID
                 FROM venue
                 WHERE :Venue = Venue_Name
                ';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
               'INSERT INTO event(Event_Date, Artist_ID, Venue_ID, Price)
                VALUES (:Event_Date, $artist, $venue, :Price)');

        $stmt->bindparam('Artist_ID', $_POST[$artist], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stmt->bindparam('Venue_ID', $_POST[$venue], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam('Date', $_POST[':Date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam('Price', $_POST[':Price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $newId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        exit;
?>
```

This is the code for the drop down list:

```
<select name='Artist' id=':Artist'>
<?php
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
      'SELECT Artist_Name 
       FROM artist 
       ORDER BY Artist_Name');
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($Artist);
       $stmt->store_result();
       while($stmt->fetch())
           echo("<option> {$Artist} </option>");
?>
</select>
```

The artist and venue tables have text values that are assigned a primary key ID which is stored into the event table with the artists date and price.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what goes wrong where? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Use the `option` tag's `value` attribute: `<option value="123">foobar</option>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, select the artist id as well and pass it in your dropdown as the value like this:

```
<select name='Artist' id=':Artist'>
<?php
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
      'SELECT Artist_Name, Artist_ID
       FROM artist 
       ORDER BY Artist_Name');
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($Artist, $ID);
       $stmt->store_result();
       while($stmt->fetch())
           echo("<option value=\"$ID\"> {$Artist} </option>");
?>
</select>
```

I think you also need to update the POST elements in your code, but I'm not sure what you're doing with the :Artist type vars in the first part.  If you use the id's as the value (as i did here) then the posted value will be the id of the name they chose, you don't need to query it.

```
<?php
    $artist = $_POST['Artist'];
    $venue = $_POST['venue'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
           'INSERT INTO event(Event_Date, Artist_ID, Venue_ID, Price)
            VALUES (:Event_Date, :Artist, :Venue, :Price)');

    $stmt->bindparam(':Artist', $artist, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->bindparam(':Venue', $venue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindparam(':Event_Date', $_POST['Date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindparam(':Price', $_POST['Price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $newId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    exit;
```

?>

Comment: that seems to work thanks, but now posts null data to the table :/ any ideas?

Comment: hi, i just updated my answer to include corrections to the INSERT code - if your form is posting 'venue', 'Date', and 'Price' (in addition to 'Artist' as per the code shown) then this should work.

Comment: currently have the form ids as :Artist or :Venue etc, then after adding your code I get a pdoexception of invalid parameter number. It also states an unidentified index of Artist and Venue after adding the revised code

Comment: did you try getting rid of the colon from your post vars?  You have two options: 1)  at least try to understand whats happening to make some progress on your own. or 2) post all of your code if you expect someone else to do it for you

Comment: if i took the colon out it posted null data, managed to get it working posting the ids just need to make the user select text eg.Lady Gaga instead of artist id eg. 3 and still post just the artists id i am trying to understand it its just throwing new problems at me that ive not experienced with php so have no idea how to solve